# Crear listas de string

Tags: string, c, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy tratando de copiar las palabras de un `file .txt` en una lista enlazada. Escribì algo pero lo que pasa es que el programa se cierra en un momento, como si hubiera un error el la asignaciòn de la memoria. No entiendo donde me estoy equivocando.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct s_nodo
{
    char* palabra;
    struct s_nodo*sig;
};
typedef struct s_nodo* t_nodo;

void agregar (t_nodo*,char*);
void imprimir(t_nodo);

int main()
{
    char aux[30];
    t_nodo lista=NULL;
    FILE*fd;
    fd=fopen("c:\\texto.txt","r");
    while(!feof(fd))
    {
        fscanf(fd,"%s",aux);
        agregar(&lista,aux);

    }
     imprimir(lista);
    return 0;
}


void agregar (t_nodo*lista,char *aux)
{

    if(*lista==NULL)
    {
        *lista=malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
        (*lista)->palabra=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy((*lista)->palabra,aux);
        (*lista)->sig=NULL;

    }
    else agregar(&(*lista)->sig,aux);    
}

void imprimir (t_nodo lista)
{
    if(lista!=NULL)
    {
        printf("-%s-",lista->palabra);
        imprimir(lista->sig);
    }
}
```

Comment: específicamente, que mensaje de error estas obteniendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dices, hay un error en la asignación de la memoria, en concreto en el segundo `malloc` dentro de la función `agregar`:

```
(*lista)->palabra=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char));
```

El problema está en el `strlen` donde haces `strlen(aux+1)`, y lo que deberías hacer es `strlen(aux)+1`. Hace ya mucho que no trabajo con punteros en C así que puede que me equivoque, pero si no recuerdo mal: al hacer `aux+1` realmente estás intentando acceder a la siguiente posición de memoria desde `aux`, y entonces el resultado de `strlen(aux+1)` no es el que esperas, creando problemas de memoria en tiempo de ejecución.

Al corregir esa línea a:

```
(*lista)->palabra=malloc((strlen(aux)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

el programa se ejecuta sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El error se encuentra en la linea:

```
(*lista)->palabra=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char));
```

de tu método agregar:

```
void agregar (t_nodo*lista,char *aux)
{
    if(*lista==NULL)
    {
        *lista=malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
        //(*lista)->palabra=malloc((strlen(aux+1))*sizeof(char)); //Error!
        (*lista)->palabra=malloc(strlen(aux)+1); // Corrige error.
        strcpy((*lista)->palabra,aux);
        (*lista)->sig=NULL;

    }
    else agregar(&(*lista)->sig,aux);
}
```

Para alojar memoria únicamente necesitas : `malloc( )` , no es necesario `*sizeof(char)`

Comment: En cuanto a la última línea, esto es así porque char está garantizado que ocupa exactamente 1 byte. Para cualquier otro tipo t, sí es necesario multiplicar por el tamaño de t para reservar x elementos: malloc(x * sizeof(t)). Así, en todo caso, yo modificaría la línea para decir "Para reservar memoria para caracteres (char), únicamente necesitas (...)"